# Font problems on certain parts of site

Tags: html, css, fonts

one of my client website uses font called Roboto. When I look on their pages all looks fine and font is working properly on all of them.

However they say that their products pages http://lichtblick-led.de/index.php/produkte.html showing other font instead of Roboto. Again, they say its only on that page and not on other pages.

Can any of you replicate the same problem?

P.S. They said they tested it from all browsers, few different computers, and even cleared the cache.

Cheers!

Comment: How are you providing the font Roboto to the page? Google Fonts? @font-face?

Comment: On which browser are they experiencing the issue? On all browsers? (it doesn't look like...)

Comment: Well not only font issues...on Firefox you have a javascript error, wheel is not defined. So you don't even see the images loaded with lazy loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after an inspection of the page I noticed that it's not using the Roboto font

```
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700&amp;subset=latin,cyrillic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

that is font **Lora**.

this needs to be changed

**under HTML:**

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700,400&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

OR

**under CSS:**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700,400&subset=latin,cyrillic);
```

You can further modify your selection over here on [GoogleFonts](http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Roboto)

PS: I have included the latin & cyrillic subsets.

Comment: That is not true. If you inspect the page you see that:
Font
===============================
font-family (stack): Roboto,"Lora",serif

Font being rendered: Roboto
font-size: 13px

Comment: true but just setting `font-family: Roboto;` won't work unless the style-sheets are linked; which in this case is not. Please see the `<head></head>` section under HTML inspector

Comment: I know that, you don't need only to check the head to see what fonts are loaded. I see that is loading Lora there but it's not the point. There are many other ways. For example check your network tab on the console and then filter by fonts. Also using an plugin for the browser can help to recognize which font is being rendered.

Comment: Here's the result: http://s11.postimg.org/4cjgecadf/Capture.png. No sign of Roboto.

Comment: I am aware of that...no doubt he's not loading the font correctly. There are also other issues on the site...and many inconsistencies between one browser to another. :)

Comment: yeah probably, I didn't check on other browsers.

Comment: I couldn't find the font base64 encoded in a file either.

Comment: true, just check the code and font is not visible there. Strange and Im sure I added it inside header. Gone check that, thanks.

Comment: do accept if this answered your question correctly :-)

Answer (score 1):

The link to load the Roboto font from the Goolge CDN isn't present on the products page:

```
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,300italic&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Also you should load the fonts before the JavaScript to prevent [FOUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).

Comment: Strange, Im sure I added the link inside header. Gone check it again. Thanks for suggestion.